# Removing pungency from onions

Tags: onions

I am from Gujarat,India.at restaurants in my city,they provide raw sliced onion as condiment.it tastes really sweet and not at all pungent. How can I remove pungency from onion?I tried soaking them in cold water but they become wet and I just want them dry.